# git push resuming previous push

Tags: git, push

I screwed up.  I modified my .gitignore to inadvertantly start tracking a directory of misc files that are huge.  When I pushed to origin I realized it was taking forever and saw my error.  I have removed (I think) the files from being tracked, but now whenever I go to push again it somehow picks up right where it left off before -- in the middle of uploading all those huge files.  I keep control-c to stop the push.  I want to stop git from resuming previous push and just push afresh this lastest commit.

Comment: Are the files still in your commit history?

Comment: I'm not a git wizard, so forgive me for being fuzzy on this:  I can look at the logs and see that the files were added, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you removed the file in the next commit, the old commit is still there and that will still be pushed.

You have to do a `git reset --hard <sha hash of commit before adding the misc files>`.

Once you do above, the commit where you added the files will be gone. You can now start working and push.

If you have other commits ( that you need) between adding those files and now, you can do a `git rebase -i <hash before file adding>` and remove the commit where you added the files